# Call subreport using C# custom code from main report SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a situation where i need to use custom code in main report to call a subreport. I have added assembly into report. I call a method in assembly i.e. GenerateReport(), which return rendered HTML of subreport. I need to show that rendered HTML in new page. How can i do that, any help

Answer (score 0):

To load a new page containing HTML generated from custom code is beyond the capabilities of SSRS.

However, you could use javascript to open a report url in a new window:

http://www.resultdata.com/ssrs-opening-a-report-in-a-new-browser-window/

Comment: Thing is, ny client does not want to see report parameters in URL. Thats why i am looking for a workaround. I generated main report HTML using SOAP API's. And, i am hoping that i can do the same for sub reports.